# python filter: Return tuple from list of strings with target strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nlp

I have a long list of 1.5m sentences and a similarly long list of words that I am looking for within the list of sentences. For example:

```
list_of_words = ['Turin', 'Milan']
list_of_sents = ['This is a sent about turin.', 'This is a sent about manufacturing.']
```

I have the following function that is able to quickly identify those sentences with the keywords and computational time is rather important so I would like to avoid for loops if able:

```
def find_keyword_comments(test_comments,test_keywords):
    keywords = '|'.join(test_keywords)
    word = re.compile(r"^.*\b({})\b.*$".format(keywords), re.I)
    newlist = filter(word.match, test_comments)
    final = list(newlist)
    return final
```

Instead of returning a list of strings that contain the keyword, I would like it to return a list of tuples with the word matched on and the string that contains the location. So it currently returns:

```
final = ['This is a sent about turin.']
```

and I would like it to return

```
final = [('Turin', 'This is a sent about turin.')]
```

Is there a syntax functionality that I am misusing or forgetting?

Comment: You say you want a list of tuples, but your example output is a list of strings, with no tuples. Could you clarify what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can take each keyword and find all comments that contain the word:

```
import re
def find_keyword_comments(test_comments,test_keywords):
   return [(word, [c for c in test_comments if re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), c, flags=re.I)]) for word in test_keywords]

list_of_words = ['Turin', 'Milan']
list_of_sents = ['This is a sent about turin.', 'This is a sent about manufacturing.']
print(find_keyword_comments(list_of_sents, list_of_words))
```

Output:

```
[('Turin', ['This is a sent about turin.']), ('Milan', [])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
import re

list_of_words = ['Turin', 'Milan']
list_of_sents = ['This is a sent about turin.', 'This is a sent about manufacturing.']

print([[x, y] for x in list_of_words for y in list_of_sents if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(x.lower()), y.lower())])
# [['Turin', 'This is a sent about turin.']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is there anyway to do this without a for loop? Computational time is a bit of an issue with this project.

Comment: @JackReimer I don't think there's a way without loop because you need to check for every items. (Sorry for my late reply)